# On Piano, What are the correct fingers to play A then D then F on right hand?

Tags: piano, fingering

Apologies for not being clear in my question.

I am looking to play an Easy version of Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata - per the link below.

A,D,F are the first 3 separate notes (not a chord) on the right hand followed by Bb (flat), D, F, which is then followed by Bb,Eb,G

I use fingers 1,4,5 but fingers 1,2,4 feels more natural - which is correct?

Note: In reviewing finger mappings to keys I see advice to map fingers to 5 consecutive keys where possible.

I've had feedback from the 1 person i know who plays piano and he says 1,4,5. Just wondering what the consensus is?

The reason for this question is that A,D,F span 6 keys so was wondering how you generally map 5 fingers to a 6 key span?

For more clarity - here are my fingers for the first few bars. Note: I have chosen this order for accuracy over comfort as using this finger ordering I don't have to move my hands and can play the piece without looking at the keyboard.

[image: Left and Right Hand Finger Use]

Comment: Whatever supports the music in a practical way is "correct". It depends on what happens before and after it. Is F the last note of the whole song? Is there something before the A?

Comment: This is less a question of comfort ability or physiolog. It depends of the chords or melody tones before and after this chord  or sequence.

Comment: Sorry in advance, but there's not enough information contained here for a helpful answer to be proffered. I tried, but that's all it is.

Comment: What is finger 5?  We don't have that on guitar.

Comment: @John Blair Can you please send a picture/screenshot of the sheet music so we can help you accordingly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The guess is that you mean on piano, right hand. If not, this answer is rubbish.

There is ***NO*** correct way to play anything on piano. There is the way that might be correct (or appropriate) for *you*. Since everyone's physiology isn't the same, players will use different fingerings. There's also the factor that isn't included in this question - what precedes and what follows that particular sequence of notes. Those facts will have an important bearing on what may be 'best'.That F may need a thumb, if the next part goes higher. But again, best is what suits you. My 'best' may well be different.

As is so often said here - your teacher will look at what you are doing, and offer appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hopefully I've clarified the question. I'm teaching myself to play the piano so no teacher to ask so using this forum instead.

Comment: Often, your 5 'fingers' won't span quite enough. onsider that the spread between thumb and rest of fingers is always wider than between each finger. So keeping thumb on the lowest note, spread the fingers to the right, and use whichever feels most comfortable. personally, 1 3 5 works there for me. But I don't have your hands... And then Bb D F again 1 3 5. Yes, thumb on a black key does work!